# feminine colloquialisms to connote platonic endearment:

Tags: hailnames

It seems as though in the U.S./in English we have a million words to connote endearment to men(albeit in a somewhat strange way) that are used with varying degrees of gender neutrality. But I'm wondering if anyone has any traditionally feminine terms of endearment or terms of endearment traditionally used for women?

Comment: How does ***grammatical*** gender enter into matters here? Do you mean nicknames used in direct address, or simple references that likely preclude sexual relationships? Calling people something that isn't their name to their face is risky, Buttercup. Do you just mean a friend who is a girl? Do you say that to her face, or merely when referring to her?

Answer (score 0):

***[Doll](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/doll)*** is used  as feminine  colloquialism

> d. Used as a term of endearment.

(American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language)

Comment: So this is a word used by women but not by men?  What makes it grammatically feminine?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=doll+meaning&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=insv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__u_989fuAhWPnqQKHePdAGMQ_AUoAXoECBEQAQ&biw=768&bih=909&dpr=2

Comment: We do not care for Let Me Google That For You links here, nor for their moral equivalents.